# EF Core xunit assert whether .Include was called

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit

I've got extension methods in .net core that effectively dynamically evaluate stuff, and will call `.Include()` on an `IQueryable<T>`. I'd like to build unit tests that test that.

Because I'm simply trying to validate .Include is called, I don't think I necessarily need to have a real db context present, but I'm failing to understand how I would assert whether my returned `IQueryable<T>` has called `.Include()`.

I am aware I could probably use an InMemory provider and literally just test that the returned values returned the specified .Included properties, but I'd like to avoid hooking up to a db (InMemory or otherwise)

Comment: _but I'd like to avoid hooking up to a db_ - without testing actual implementation, tests going to be fragile, because you are going to rewrite tests every time you improving query used in the method

Comment: `Include` is *only* used to eagerly load related data. It doesn't specify any joins or relations. You don't need to assert whether it was called or not to check whether a property is `Null` or a collection is empty

Comment: What does your extension method do and why do you want to check whether `Include` is called? Is `Include` misused perhaps? As for `avoid hooking up to a db` that's self-contradictory. You're trying to test the eager loading behavior of an ORM. The very thing you're trying to test is the way the *provider* is eagerly loading the data. An RDBMS provider may use a JOIN, or multiple queries in a single batch. CosmosDB doesn't support it at all